# Open links from an external website that sits in an Iframe in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website with an iframe on one page that goes to an external URL (which I have no control over). I am trying to find a way to have all the links in the Iframe (not the entire page) open in a new window. I've tried a couple solutions with no luck. Is there a way I can target the iframe and use the HTML base tag?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the Same Origin Policy, you can only modify the contents of an iframe if the domains and protocols match.

Comment: I am amazed at how very few people are aware of the same origin policy. I did however once accessed the content of an iframe loading a page from different domain and modify it using virtual hosts and proxiying on my apache server. But that was for a very special case, and I believe the OP won't implement that. ;)

Comment: So you're saying there is no way I can target my iframe and say "any link in the Iframe open in a new window?

Comment: Exactly. However, if the domains and protocols matched (e.g., an iframe of `http://www.example.com/myiframe.html` inside `http://www.example.com/myiframe.html`), you could do this.